# Convert timedelta64[ns] column to seconds in Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

A pandas DataFrame column `duration` contains `timedelta64[ns]` as shown. How can you convert them to seconds?

```
0   00:20:32
1   00:23:10
2   00:24:55
3   00:13:17
4   00:18:52
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I tried the following

```
print df[:5]['duration'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
```

but got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    print df[0:5]['duration'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 130, in wrapper
    "addition and subtraction, but the operator [%s] was passed" % name)
TypeError: can only operate on a timedeltas for addition and subtraction, but the operator [__div__] was passed
```

Also tried

```
print df[:5]['duration'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

but received the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print df[:5]['duration'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 934, in astype
    values = com._astype_nansafe(self.values, dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 1653, in _astype_nansafe
    raise TypeError("cannot astype a timedelta from [%s] to [%s]" % (arr.dtype,dtype))
TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [timedelta64[s]]
```

Comment: this is fixed recent releases; as in the [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blame/778cfe43a4cef52442e00fe505290079a717f515/pandas/core/ops.py#L304), if both sides are timedelta addition, subtraction and _division_ are supported. that section of the code was changed back in 2013

Comment: @behzad.nouri is right, I believe this was fixed in > 0.13.1 (maybe needs 0.14), but current is 0.15.0: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion

Comment: @behzad.nouri Thanks, updating to Pandas 0.15.0 and numpy 1.9.0 got it to work.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This works properly in the current version of Pandas (version 0.14):

```
In [132]: df[:5]['duration'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
Out[132]: 
0    1232
1    1390
2    1495
3     797
4    1132
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

Here is a workaround for older versions of Pandas/NumPy:

```
In [131]: df[:5]['duration'].values.view('<i8')/10**9
Out[131]: array([1232, 1390, 1495,  797, 1132], dtype=int64)
```

timedelta64 and datetime64 data are stored internally as 8-byte ints (dtype
`'<i8'`). So the above views the timedelta64s as 8-byte ints and then does integer
division to convert nanoseconds to seconds.

Note that you [need NumPy version 1.7 or newer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#numpy-datetime64-dtype-and-1-6-dependency) to work with datetime64/timedelta64s.

Answer (score 89):

Use the [Series dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#datetimelike-properties) to get access to the methods and attributes of a datetime (timedelta) series.

```
>>> s
0   -1 days +23:45:14.304000
1   -1 days +23:46:57.132000
2   -1 days +23:49:25.913000
3   -1 days +23:59:48.913000
4            00:00:00.820000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
>>>
>>> s.dt.total_seconds()
0   -885.696
1   -782.868
2   -634.087
3    -11.087
4      0.820
dtype: float64
```

---

There are other Pandas [Series Accessors](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html#accessors) for String, Categorical, and Sparse data types.

Answer (score 15):

> Just realized it's an old thread, anyway leaving it here if wanderers
> like me clicks only on top 5 results on the search engine and ends up
> here.

Make sure that your types are correct.

- If you want to convert **datetime** to **seconds** , just sum up seconds for each hour, minute and seconds of the datetime object if its for duration within one date.
- - hours - hours x 3600 = seconds
- - minutes - minutes x 60 = seconds
- - seconds - seconds

`linear_df['duration'].dt.hour*3600 + linear_df['duration'].dt.minute*60 + linear_df['duration'].dt.second`

- If you want to convert **timedelta** to **seconds** use the one bellow.

`linear_df[:5]['duration'].astype('timedelta64[s]')`

I got it to work like this:

start_dt and end_dt columns are in this format:

```
import datetime

linear_df[:5]['start_dt']

0   1970-02-22 21:32:48.000
1   2016-12-30 17:47:33.216
2   2016-12-31 09:33:27.931
3   2016-12-31 09:52:53.486
4   2016-12-31 10:29:44.611
Name: start_dt, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Had my duration in timedelta64[ns] format, which was subtraction of **start** and **end** datetime values.

```
linear_df['duration'] = linear_df['end_dt'] - linear_df['start_dt']
```

Resulted duration column look like this

```
linear_df[:5]['duration']

0          0 days 00:00:14
1   2 days 17:44:50.558000
2   0 days 15:37:28.418000
3   0 days 18:45:45.727000
4   0 days 19:21:27.159000
Name: duration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Using pandas I had my duration seconds between two dates in float. Easier to compare or filter your duration afterwards.

```
linear_df[:5]['duration'].astype('timedelta64[s]')

0        14.0
1    236690.0
2     56248.0
3     67545.0
4     69687.0
Name: duration, dtype: float64
```

In my case if I want to get all duration which is more than 1 second.

Answer (score 11):

Use the 'total_seconds()' function :

```
df['durationSeconds'] = df['duration'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use the pandas **apply()** function

```
def get_seconds(time_delta):
    return time_delta.seconds

def get_microseconds(time_delta):
    return time_delta.micro_seconds

time_delta_series = df['duration']

converted_series = time_delta_series.apply(get_seconds)
print(converted_series)
```

Comment: Although it works, it is recommended to use native functions instead of `apply()`. It is considerably faster with `dt.total_seconds()`

Answer (score 3):

Well the answers didn't age well. Here is a simpler solution :

`df.duration.dt.total_seconds()`