# Python: Pandas Series - Difference between consecutive datetime rows in seconds

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, difference, seconds

I have a pandas Series called 'df' as follows

```
                       value    
date_time_index         
2015-10-28 01:54:00     1.0 
2015-10-28 01:55:00     1.0 
2015-10-28 01:56:00     1.0 
2015-10-28 01:57:00     1.0 
2015-10-28 01:58:00     1.0
```

and I just want a new column with the difference *in seconds* between consecutive rows, how can I do this?

Note: The type is

```
 type(df.index[1])
```

given as

```
 pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

Comment: did you try df.diff()  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Comment: yes, ive been trying that for 1 hour now, but I get a difference like '0 days 00:00:01'. I cant seem to get this into seconds. There must be some simple way get what Im looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26456825/3765319 After you subtract using `.diff`, you are left with a TimeDelta column. That answer should help you.

Comment: @Kartik, yes just used that in a posted answer below at the exact same time you made your comment, but thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
df.index.to_series().diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)

date_time_index
2015-10-28 01:54:00     0.0
2015-10-28 01:55:00    60.0
2015-10-28 01:56:00    60.0
2015-10-28 01:57:00    60.0
2015-10-28 01:58:00    60.0
Name: date_time_index, dtype: float64
```

Comment: How does this understand to use `date_time_index` column?

Answer (score 3):

I think Ive worked it out using

```
df['temp_index'] = df.index
df['Delta'] = df['temp_index'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

in minutes rather than seconds (change m to s for seconds)