# How to change the time format of timedelta

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I hv a timedelta in the following format

```
0days 01:25:53.0000000
```

I want to change this time delta to equivalent 
minutes(I.e. 85.88)
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Using** `total_seconds`

```
pd.Series(pd.Timedelta('0days 01:25:53.0000000')).dt.total_seconds()/60
Out[334]: 
0    85.883333
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# Sample DataFrame
                     time
0  0days 01:25:53.0000000
```

Use **`to_timedelta`** and divide by **`pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')`**

```
pd.to_timedelta(df.time) / pd.Timedelta(1, 'm')

0    85.883333
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a comparison between the different methods you can choose from:

1. `df.timedelta / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')`
2. `df.timedelta.dt.total_seconds().div(60)`       (fastest for > 10.000 rows)
3. `df.timedelta.astype('timedelta64[s]').div(60)` (fastest for < 10.000 rows or very large sets)
4. `df.timedelta.astype('timedelta64[m]')` (will round value).

*note: this answer is in the dupe:* [Convert timedelta64[ns] column to seconds in Python Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456825/convert-timedelta64ns-column-to-seconds-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timedelta': [pd.Timedelta('0days 01:25:53.0000000'),
                  pd.Timedelta('0days 02:25:53.0000000')]
})

df['timedelta-minutes'] = df.timedelta.astype('timedelta64[s]').div(60)
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  timedelta  timedelta-minutes
0  01:25:53          85.883333
1  02:25:53         145.883333
```

#### Timings

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timedelta': [pd.Timedelta('0days 01:25:53.0000000'),
                  pd.Timedelta('0days 02:25:53.0000000')]
})

df = pd.concat([df]*5000)

%timeit df.timedelta / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')         # 638 µs per loop
%timeit df.timedelta.dt.total_seconds().div(60)       # 215 µs per loop
%timeit df.timedelta.astype('timedelta64[s]').div(60) # 213 µs per loop
%timeit df.timedelta.astype('timedelta64[m]')         # 132 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank for edit , vote back :-)

Comment: @Wen Hmm sorry.... I edited too much so made it an own answer.

Comment: @Wen I think we should mark this as dupe though.

Comment: @chrisz Turns out you were not correct (with my setup).

Comment: @chrisz Interesting... 10000 rows seems to be the breakpoint. So it is quicker until 10000 rows (2x5000). At 20000 the dt.total_seconds() becomes quicker indeed. Try it yourself with: `pd.concat([df]*2000)`