# Pandas Timedelta error with datetime64[ns, UTC] Fields

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe with the two time fields shown below.  When I try to take the Timedelta between them I'm getting the error message below.  I've included the .info() for the fields.  Does anyone see what the issue is and can you suggest how to fix it?  Any tips greatly appreciated.

```
Data:

                            et_utc                    ts_utc
0 2018-05-02 09:24:29.304000+00:00 2018-05-02 09:39:15+00:00
1 2018-05-02 09:26:12.132000+00:00 2018-05-02 09:39:15+00:00
2 2018-05-02 09:28:37.913000+00:00 2018-05-02 09:39:12+00:00
3 2018-05-02 09:28:37.913000+00:00 2018-05-02 09:28:49+00:00
4 2018-05-02 10:39:48.820000+00:00 2018-05-02 10:39:48+00:00


Data description:

df[[‘et_utc','ts_utc']].info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25625 entries, 0 to 25624
Data columns (total 2 columns):
et_utc    25625 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
ts_utc    25625 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](2)
memory usage: 1.8 MB


Code:

df['t_delta']=pd.Timedelta(df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).seconds


Error:

ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible
```

Comment: What happens if you just execute `df['t_delta']=(df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).seconds`?

Comment: @wwii thank you for getting back to me.  When I try your suggestion I get the error "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'seconds'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timedelta64\[ns\] column to seconds in Python Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456825/convert-timedelta64ns-column-to-seconds-in-python-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the timedelta in seconds,according to the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion), you can do:

```
df['t_delta']=(df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Series `dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html?highlight=accessor#dt-accessor) to get access to the methods and attributes of a datetime (timedelta) series.

```
>>> (df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).dt.total_seconds()
0   -885.696
1   -782.868
2   -634.087
3    -11.087
4      0.820
dtype: float64
>>> df['t_delta'] = (df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).dt.total_seconds()
>>>
>>> print(df)
                   et_utc              ts_utc  t_delta
0 2018-05-02 09:24:29.304 2018-05-02 09:39:15 -885.696
1 2018-05-02 09:26:12.132 2018-05-02 09:39:15 -782.868
2 2018-05-02 09:28:37.913 2018-05-02 09:39:12 -634.087
3 2018-05-02 09:28:37.913 2018-05-02 09:28:49  -11.087
4 2018-05-02 10:39:48.820 2018-05-02 10:39:48    0.820
>>>
```

[Datetimelike properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties)

---

*astyping* is equivalent to floor division, it looses a bit of resolution.

```
>>> (df['et_utc'] - df['ts_utc']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
0   -886.0
1   -783.0
2   -635.0
3    -12.0
4      0.0
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Comment: @Ben.T - the link in your answer also shows true division by a *`timedelta64[s]`*