# ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[ns]')

Tags: python, datetime

I have a problem with my code, I need to find a certain value based on some attributes.

```
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(filed, on_demand=True)
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names():
    df = pd.read_excel(filed,sheet_name)  
    df['diffspeed']=df['speed'].diff().fillna(0)
    df['timeshift'] = df['time'].shift(-1)
    df['timediff']=(df['timeshift']-df['time'])
    df['Distance']= df['diffspeed']/df['timediff']  
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name)
writer.save()
```

it keeps giving me the below error
ufunc true_divide cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('

Answer (score 3):

The data type of column `df['timediff']` is a [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) which is seen from the numpy [dtype kind](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html) `m`. It is meant to represent a difference between two `Datetime` objects and is established by the subtraction of those at line `df['timediff']=(df['timeshift']-df['time'])`. While normal `float`s do not have a unit you can look at Timedeltas as if they had one. They cannot be used as divisors because the inverse of that unit has no representation in numpy/pandas.

You can convert them to ordinary floats given in seconds by
`df['timediff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's')`
where `np` stands for `numpy`
thus the last line reads 
`df['Distance'] = df['diffspeed']/(df['timediff'] / np.timedelta64(1, 's'))`.

For further explanation see [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26457238).