# Interpolating a time series with interp1d using only numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I want to plot a time series with numpy and matplotlib, using markers for the exact points, and interpolation. Basically this (data is dummy, but functionality is the same, note that distance between time-points may vary):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = [
    np.datetime64('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
]
Z = [543, 234, 435, 765, 564, 235, 345]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(T, Z, 'o-')
```

[image]

However, the interpolation done here is just connecting the points. I want to include spline interpolation and other kinds using scipy's interp1d. So, I tried replacing the last line with the following:

```py
ax.plot(T,Z, 'o')
ax.plot(T,interp1d(T, Z)(T), '-')
```

and I get the following error:

```
UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500546/ufunc-true-divide-cannot-use-operands-with-types-dtypefloat64-and-dtypem8), I read that during interpolation I should divide `T` by `np.timedelta64(1, 's')`, like this:

```py
ax.plot(T,Z, 'o')
ax.plot(T,interp1d(T/np.timedelta64(1, 's'))(T), '-')
```

however, I get an even weirder error:

```
ufunc 'true_divide' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('<m8[s]')
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type of any element in `T` is `np.datetime64` and not `np.timedelta64`.

Thus, convert the dtype of all elements of T to `np.timedelta64` by creating  a numpy array with datatype [`m`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.kind.html):

```
T = np.array(
    np.datetime64('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
    dtype='m')
```

Then, as [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) suggests, we have to pass `x` and `y` that are convertible to float like values to `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to get a interpolation function. We'll use a method suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500952/7789963) to do that:

```
# Get an interpolation function f
f = scipy.interpolation.interp1d(x=T/np.timedelta64(1, 's'), y=Z)
```

Finally, we can use the interpolated function as follows for plotting:

```
ax.plot(T, f(T/np.timedelta64(1, 's'), '-')
```

Combining everything, we get the following output:

[image]

The code that can reproduce the image:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.array([
    np.datetime64('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-02T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-03T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-05T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-06T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-09T00:00:00.000000000'),
    np.datetime64('2020-01-13T00:00:00.000000000'),
], dtype='m')

Z = [543, 234, 435, 765, 564, 235, 345]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(T, Z, 'o')

f = interp1d(x=T/np.timedelta64(1, 's'), y=Z)

ax.plot(T, f(T/np.timedelta64(1, 's')), '-')
plt.show()
```