# AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds' with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to convert sniffTime into a number of seconds. I have already looked at [Convert timedelta64[ns] column to seconds in Python Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456825/convert-timedelta64ns-column-to-seconds-in-python-pandas-dataframe) however that solution did not work. I think that perhaps the line pandas line may be at fault.

```
print(sniffTime)
print(type(sniffTime))
```

Outputs:

```
821693000 nanoseconds
<class 'numpy.timedelta64'>
```

Error

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

On Line:

```
df['PerSec']=df['PerSec'].div(sniffTime.total_seconds())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert numpy scalar to [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html), so is possible use [`Timedelta.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html):

```
df['PerSec']=df['PerSec'].div(pd.Timedelta(sniffTime).total_seconds())
```